# Issue with openpyxl while exporting format in excel

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am updating my Python Dataframe using **conditional formatting**. Code that I am using is **working fine with Python Dataframe**, however when I export it on Excel (`.to_excel`) using `openpyxl`, it **randomly** export conditional formatting by column/field.

Can you please help in this regard?

(A) **Code (Sample)** used for formatting:-

```
df_formatted = df_to_format.style\
    .applymap (lambda x: 'background-color: %s' %  'purple' if str(x)[0:4] == 'Coun' else 'background-color: %s' % 'none', subset=['Sheet1'])\
    .applymap (lambda x: 'background-color: %s' %  'gray' if str(x)[0:4] == 'This' else 'background-color: %s' % 'none', subset=['Sheet1'])\
    .applymap (lambda x: 'background-color: %s' %  'yellow' if str(x)[0:3] == 'Low' else 'background-color: %s' % 'none', subset=['Sheet1'])\
    .applymap (lambda x: 'background-color: %s' %  'pink' if str(x)[0:4] == 'High' else 'background-color: %s' % 'none', subset=['Sheet1'])\
.to_excel('styled.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', index=False)
```

(B) **Expected** Formatting Export

[image]

(C) **Actual** Formatting Export

[image]

Comment: Hi, Is there any possible solution to the issue or any alternative to export the formatted Dataframe as Excel Worksheet? Please suggest

Comment: got a solution, since I was using repetitive lambda function on same field was causing this issue, I put all the condition in if-elif-else format then it worked.